# Variation in Signal Power in Mimo system

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, dft, signal-detection, music

I am exploring methods for reducing computations required by MUSIC (Multiple Signal Classification) Algorithm. Most of the computational power is spent on calculating SVD.

My approach is to take fourier transform of signal matrix and perform filtering to make it sparse; calculating SVD on sparse matrix takes much lesser time.
Usually, when filtering, the determining factor is not the noise itself, but spectrum leakage due to DFT. Smaller terms due to spectrum leakage also get removed when filtering.

My question is, is there limit in MIMO systems as to how much difference in power of two signals can be. For example, lets suppose, no of signals transmitted are 10. Is there a rule as to how high in power Signal 1 can be in comparison to Signal X.
$$ \frac{Signal-1}{Signal-X} <= K $$ whre X is not equal to 1. Can K be indefinitely large ?

Also, do you think sparseFFT with Cheby-Shev or any other proper filter can help in containing the leakages ? Deconvolving using windows is entirely out of question because it would increase the computations to the point of making the whole approach infeasible.